# Open a new map view with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5, qgis-custom-widgets

I'd like to use PyQGIS to open a new map view with its own map canvas & coordinate system. This seems like a very basic questions but I can't find any information about it! I suppose I can somehow embed a new `MapCanvas` instance inside a `QWidget`, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: See the [PyQGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html?highlight=qgsmapcanvas#embedding-map-canvas).

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Thank you. I had looked at the cookbook already but apparently I had not understood it as the task was far easier than I realized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map=QgsMapCanvas()
map.show()
```

Afterwards handle the events and use methods like,
map.setExtent()
map.setLayers([layer]).

If you are doing it in QT Designer make a Widget and promote it to QgsMapCanvas.
Rest Pyuic5.bat will take care.